# what is the difference between make([]string) and []string{}

Tags: go

I  make  global declaration of a value.

```
var {
     b = make([]string,10)  //way 1
     a = []string{}         //way 2
}
```

Both ways work. Can someone make detailed explanation of the difference between them?

Comment: This is explained [in the tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/13), [in the spec](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types), and [on the blog](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals).

Answer (score 7):

The expression `make([]string,10)` returns a slice with length and capacity of 10.  The expression `[]string{}` returns a slice with length and capacity of 0.

[Check it out on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/mfwL4xFUgU).